new command or environment with two minted environments inside a listing environment
I'm trying to define a new command or environment that replicates the following code.
\begin{listing}[h]
\begin{minted}[linenos]{python}
# some python code
\end{minted}
\begin{minted}{python}
# the results of executing the code
\end{minted}
\end{listing}

The python code and the results would be arguments passed to the new environment or command. I tried defining a new command as
\newcommand{\code}[2]{
\begin{listing}[h]
\caption{capt}
\begin{minted}[linenos]{python}
#1
\end{minted}
\begin{minted}{python}
#2
\end{minted}
\end{listing}
}

and use it as
\code{python code}{python result}

but it throws a lot of errors, including a FancyVerb error.
I also have defined an environment, but it has no arguments and has only one minted environment in it's definition. I'm not sure how to put two minted environments inside a new environment.
Thanks for the help.

Have a look at How to wrap floated minted listing in my own environment? and Caption and label on Minted code.

After attempting to work with the reply, may I simply suggest not doing so? It's not very versatile, and it would be easier for you to typeset the code and output manually.

This and this may also be of interest. Page 33 in the minted documentation may also be useful.
